# Speed problem for summation (sum of divisors)

Tags: c++, c++11

I should implement this summation in C ++. I have tried with this code, but with very high numbers up to 10 ^ 12 it takes too long.

The summation is: [image: summation]

For any positive integer k, let d(k) denote the number of positive divisors of k (including 1 and k itself).
For example, for the number 4: 1 has 1 divisor, 2 has two divisors, 3 has two divisors, and 4 has three divisors. So the result would be 8.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int findDivisors(long long n) 
{
    int c=0;
    for(int j=1;j*j<=n;j++)
    {
        if(n%j==0)
        {
            c++;
            if(j!=(n/j))
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

long long compute(long long n)
{
    long long sum=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        sum += (findDivisors(i));
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n, divisors;

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    cin >> n;

    cout << compute(n);
}
```

I think it's not just a simple optimization problem, but maybe I should change the algorithm entirely.
Would anyone have any ideas to speed it up? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at some information about computing [divisor functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) to try to bring this down from an O(n^2) approach. Maybe try building up a table of primes to find factorizations?

Comment: You can't loop 1 to 10^12. It will definitely get you a TLE.

Comment: As often with this kind of problem, this sum actually counts pairs x, y where x divides y, and the sum is arranged to count first all x corresponding to a fixed y, but nothing says you have to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[largest_prime_is_463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/largest-prime-is-463035818)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67494972/4944425) shows an O(N) solution, but the OP is trying to solve this problem

> with very high numbers up to 10<sup>12</sup>.

The following is an O(N<sup>1/2</sup>) algorithm, based on some observations about the sum

> n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n

In particular, we can count the number of terms with a specific value.

Consider all the terms n/k where k > n/2. There are n/2 of those and all are equal to 1 (integer division), so that their sum is n/2.

Similar considerations hold for the other dividends, so that we can write the following function

```
long long count_divisors(long long n)
{
    auto sum{ n };
    for (auto i{ 1ll }, k_old{ n }, k{ n }; i < k ; ++i, k_old = k)
    { //                                    ^^^^^ it goes up to sqrt(n)
        k = n / (i + 1);
        sum += (k_old - k) * i;
        if (i == k)
            break;
        sum += k;
    }
    
    return sum;   
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/zG4M39fGq) it is tested against the O(N) algorithm, the only difference in the results beeing the corner cases n = 0 and n = 1.

**Edit**

Thanks again to largest_prime_is_463035818, who linked the Wikipedia page about the [divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function), where both an O(N) and an O(sqrt(N)) algorithm are mentioned.

An implementation of the latter may look like this

```
auto divisor_summatory(long long n)
{
    auto sum{ 0ll };
    auto k{ 1ll };
    for ( ; k <= n / k; ++k )
    {
        sum += n / k;
    }
    --k;
    return 2 * sum - k * k;
}
```

They also add this statement:

> Finding a closed form for this summed expression seems to be beyond the techniques available, but it is possible to give approximations. The leading behavior of the series is given by
>
> D(x) = xlogx + x(2γ - 1) + Δ(x)
>
> where γ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and the error term is Δ(x) = O(sqrt(x)).

Comment: Thanks, this solution works with all subtasks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was hoping for a `O(1)` and didnt find it, but this is nice.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Me too and it may very well exist, but it's beyond my knowledge ;)

Comment: what makes me doubt is that with reals the sum evaluates to a simple expression involving harmonic numbers https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%2Fk++k+from+1+to+n , though I am not a aware of a way to compute harmonic numbers without a loop. Integer artihmetics adds more complications. But your approach looks promising, maybe it can be taken a step further.

Comment: after turning in circles a bit more I gave up and tried to see what literature has to say about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function Note the part that says: "This allows us to provide an alternative expression for D(x), and a simple way to compute it in O ( sqrt(x) ) time: ..." and then the formula that corresponds to my implementation and then the one for yours :) And further: "Finding a closed form for this summed expression seems to be beyond the techniques available, but it is possible to give approximations"

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for the link, that seems like a way cleaner implementation of "my" reinvented wheel ;)

Comment: with the help of hints in your solution and in the wiki article I came up with something more readable: https://godbolt.org/z/PMxxTf33c. How about adding it to your answer? I mean without your solution I wasnt able to get it and I don't feel like changing my answer completely

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I took the liberty to modify your suggestion, changing the condition from `i*i <= n` to `i <= n / i`. The duplicated division should be optimized away (gcc does it) and it should avoid a (remotely) possible overflow. Thanks again.

Comment: good to know about the division vs multiplication, though `sum` overflows much sonner if I am not mistaken, and there still is `k*k` on the `return`.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 True, but I'd avoid that UB on a loop condition if possible, as I think it's more "dangerous" than a wrong returned value.

Answer (score 1):

I used your brute force approach as reference to have test cases. The ones I used are

```
compute(12) == 35
cpmpute(100) == 482
```

Don't get confused by computing factorizations. There are some tricks one can play when factorizing numbers, but you actually don't need any of that. The solution is a plain simple `O(N)` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

long long compute(long long n){
    long long sum = n+1;
    for (long long i=2; i < n ; ++i){
        sum += n/i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << compute(12) << "\n";
    std::cout << compute(100) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
35
482
```

Why does this work?

The key is in Marc Glisse's comment:

> As often with this kind of problem, this sum actually counts pairs x,
> y where x divides y, and the sum is arranged to count first all x
> corresponding to a fixed y, but nothing says you have to keep it that
> way.

I could stop here, because the comment already explains it all. Though, if it didn't click yet...

The trick is to realize that it is much simpler to count divisors of all numbers up to `n` rather than `n`-times counting divisors of individual numbers and take the sum.

You don't need to care about factorizations of eg `123123123` or `52323423` to count all divisors up to `10000000000`. All you need is a change of perspective. Instead of trying to factorize numbers, consider the divisors. How often does the divisor `1` appear up to `n`? Simple: `n`-times. How often does the divisor `2` appear? Still simple: `n/2` times, because every second number is divisible by `2`. Divisor `3`? Every 3rd number is divisible by `3`. I hope you can see the pattern already.

You could even reduce the loop to only loop till `n/2`, because bigger numbers obviously appear only once as divisor. Though I didn't bother to go further, because the biggest change is from your `O(N * sqrt(N))` to `O(N)`.

Comment: Very nice observation @largest_prime_is_463035818 as when we calculate the sum of divisors we have to consider the number of occurrence of ```n/i``` and by the correlated pattern, it will appear ```i``` times. So multiplying with ```i``` will give the sum of divisors. But here we only considered the count of divisors.

Comment: @BadhanSen there is no multiplying with `i` its just the sum of `n/i` for `i = 1 till n` (actually the initial sum of n+1 and loop starting at 2 only going till n-1 is only due to a small confusion of mine, but it adds up right)

Comment: @BadhanSen " But here we only considered the count of divisors. " thats what the question is about. In all the excitment I actually didnt bother to understand your answer completely. Are you summing the divisors? Thats not what the question is asking for

Comment: Yes, @largest_prime_is_463035818 I am saying the sum of all divisors from 1 to n technique.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off with some math and reduce the `O(n * sq(n))` factorization to `O(n * log(log(n)))` and for counting the sum of divisors the overall complexity is `O(n * log(log(n)) + n * n^(1/3))`.

**For instance:**

In Codeforces [himanshujaju](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22317) explains how we can optimize the solution of finding divisors of a number.
I am simplifying it a little bit.

```
Let, n as the product of three numbers p, q, and r.

so assume p * q * r = n, where p <= q <= r. 
The maximum value of p = n^(1/3).

Now we can loop over all prime numbers in a range [2, n^(1/3)]
and try to reduce the time complexity of prime factorization.

We will split our number n into two numbers x and y => x * y = n. 

And x contains prime factors up to n^(1/3) and y deals with higher prime factors greater than n^(1/3).

Thus gcd(x, y) = 1.
Now define F(n) as the number of prime factors of n. 

From multiplicative rules, we can say that 

F(x * y) = F(x) * F(y), if gcd(x, y) = 1.

For finding F(n) => F(x * y) = F(x) * F(y)

So first find F(x) then F(y) will F(n/x)

And there will 3 cases to cover for y:
1. y is a prime number: F(y) = 2.
2. y is the square of a prime number: F(y) = 3.
3. y is a product of two distinct prime numbers: F(y) = 4.

So once we are done with finding F(x) and F(y), we are also done with finding F(x * y) or F(n).
```

In [Cp-Algorithm](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/divisors.html) there is also a nice explanation of how to count the number of divisors on a number. And also in [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-divisors-n-on13/) a nice coding example of how to count the number of divisors of a number in an efficient way. One can check the articles and can generate a nice solution to this problem.

**C++ implementation**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int maxn = 1e6 + 11;
bool prime[maxn];
bool primesquare[maxn];
int table[maxn]; // for storing primes

void SieveOfEratosthenes()
{

    for(int i = 2; i < maxn; i++){
        prime[i] = true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < maxn; i++){
        primesquare[i] = false;
    }

    // 1 is not a prime number
    prime[1] = false;

    for(int p = 2; p * p < maxn; p++){
        // If prime[p] is not changed, then
        // it is a prime
        if(prime[p] == true){
            // Update all multiples of p
            for(int i = p * 2; i < maxn; i += p){
                prime[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    int j = 0;
    for(int p = 2; p < maxn; p++) {
        if (prime[p]) {
            // Storing primes in an array
            table[j] = p;

            // Update value in primesquare[p * p],
            // if p is prime.
            if(p < maxn / p) primesquare[p * p] = true;
            j++;
        }
    }
}

// Function to count divisors
int countDivisors(int n)
{
    // If number is 1, then it will have only 1
    // as a factor. So, total factors will be 1.
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    // ans will contain total number of distinct
    // divisors
    int ans = 1;

    // Loop for counting factors of n
    for(int i = 0;; i++){
        // table[i] is not less than cube root n
        if(table[i] * table[i] * table[i] > n)
            break;

        // Calculating power of table[i] in n.
        int cnt = 1; // cnt is power of prime table[i] in n.
        while (n % table[i] == 0){ // if table[i] is a factor of n
            n = n / table[i];
            cnt = cnt + 1; // incrementing power
        }

        // Calculating the number of divisors
        // If n = a^p * b^q then total divisors of n
        // are (p+1)*(q+1)
        ans = ans * cnt;
    }

    // if table[i] is greater than cube root of n

    // First case
    if (prime[n])
        ans = ans * 2;

    // Second case
    else if (primesquare[n])
        ans = ans * 3;

    // Third case
    else if (n != 1)
        ans = ans * 4;

    return ans; // Total divisors
}

int main()
{
    SieveOfEratosthenes();
    int sum = 0;
    int n = 5;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum += countDivisors(i);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
n = 4 => 8
n = 5 => 10
```

**Complexity**

Time complexity: `O(n * log(log(n)) + n * n^(1/3))`

Space complexity: `O(n)`

Thanks, @largest_prime_is_463035818 for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't understand the data your implementation prints. For the number 5: 1 has 1 divisor, 2 has two divisors, 3 has two divisors, 4 has three divisors and 5 has 2 divisors. So the result would be 10

Comment: Hi! @user14584436, first I misunderstood your problem as it called the sum of divisors. So I implemented it that way. Now you can check my explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I understand your implementation, but the problem does not work with numbers up to 10 ^ 12. How can I increase the maximum computable number? Thank you

Comment: Actually, it is not possible to loop through 1 to 10^12. So, some mathematical explanation may exist but currently, I don't know how to calculate the sum of divisors count up to 10^12.

Comment: you changed some wording and the code seems to be yours, but this  still looks like plagiarism: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22317. Please properly give attribution when copying large chunks from somewhere

Comment: actually there is clear differences but the similarities are too striking. For example "We have only these three cases since there can be at max two prime factors of Y. If it would have had more than two prime factors, one of them would surely have been <=N^(1/3) , and hence it would be included in X and not in Y." is word by word what you write, this cannot happen by chance

Comment: Yes, I actually read that blog and I am finding a solution for 10^12 and also plan to edit and give the referances.

Comment: dont do it later but from the start. Already copying paragraphs or parts without proper attribution is plagiarism. When you directly quote from the text, the quotes should be marked to be recognisable as quotes

Comment: Thanks, @largest_prime_is_463035818 for the suggestion. I will remember that. And Actually, there are only 2 blogs on this article for efficient explanation. One on Codeforces: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22317 and the other is E-max: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/divisors.html

Comment: dont get me wrong, but its not a kind suggestion but a request. Plagiarism is no fun. I flagged this answer for moderators attention. If you ask me in its current state the answer should be deleted

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion and I will follow in the future.

Comment: it is not sufficient to add a note along the line of "For more explanation, the bellow reference will be helpful". As I said already, quotes must be marked such that they can be recognized as quotes. Prentending someone else words are yours can be a crime. For more information see eg here: https://www.plagiarism.org/article/what-is-plagiarism

Comment: fwiw, I appreciate that you actually tried to change the answer. I do take plagiarism seriously and I think so should you. I still think it should be more clear what parts are copied directly and what parts have been modified, though I wouldn't have complained that much if I had read the answer like it is now. I just hope the code is not stolen from elsewhere, tbh it looks suspicious, but I didn't find it online.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I really appreciate your approach. As I am learning through my mistake, and mentor like you is an asset to the community.

Comment: Badhan Sen, could you, just to be clear about it, explicitly state that no part of this answer  was copied from anywhere else? I want to make sure that there is no misunderstanding. I am with largest_prime that phrasings like "For finding F(n), we use the naive trial division ..." read very much like a textbook or introductory article. You did change that, but changing phrasings is not the point here. Instead we need to be sure that you understand that copying any part of it, even with little rephrasings, would be the problem here. So can you comment "Nothing here was copied from anywhere." ?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I have to explain the code which I learn from GeeksForGeeks, Cp-Algorithm, and Codeforces. As It is a method to find sum of divisors not the count of divisors. So I got the idea and help from the article and write the code according to the answer.

Comment: Please link those articles which inspired and helped you and use the quote formatting for whatever you copied from them. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Then your contribution is appreciated.

Comment: @Yunnosch, thanks for the recommendation. I added the article and references which help me to find the answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks for attributing cleanly. Just have another look at the help on formatting, I think you used code formatting for what should be quote-formatted, but most users will already understand that you are formatting the quoted parts. Just for perfection use the "> text" formatting.